# Is ns2 installable for M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, ns2, ns-3

In our Lab, we were asked to install ns2. I tried running a script from a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/poz1/NS2). But, after executing, it failed to run. I saw this [ns3 google group](https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users/c/5Kaswr9m6-s%20where). It mentioned that ns-3.33 was able to install in her system. But it didn't mention ns2. I haven't been able to find any material which points to any ns2 installation. Can anyone confirm if it is even possible, as this software is quite old, and my architecture is ARM?

Comment: Hints: 1.  https://github.com/aemreunal/ns-allinone-2.35-Mac-OS-10.9-install-patch ... **2**. A later version of "ns2 install-osx" https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/ns-install-osx .... **3**. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d6IZWg4IxHE07HSCW7n1sxh0-22CivQS?usp=share_link ..... Other obstacles can be : Missing libXmu headers. And maybe the compiler must be an older version?

Comment: @KnudLarsen Actually, the compiler needs to be g++4.8. But homebrew doesn't maintain it anymore. Do you know where to get the older version?

Comment: Actually g++ version 5.x is OK, if it's a no PIE version. ... (And if all MDART code is removed, any later no PIE gcc/g++ will often work OK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got the help of [one of the developers of ns-3](https://www.tomh.org/). He was kind enough to help me with the installation, and he mentioned the steps which were required for the installation at: [https://www.nsnam.org/~tomh/ns-2-mac-m1-instructions.pdf](https://www.nsnam.org/%7Etomh/ns-2-mac-m1-instructions.pdf)

I followed the steps mentioned in this, and it worked perfectly.